# Uart / GPS driver sample buffer overflow

Tags: uart, raspberry-pi3, baud-rate, android-things

I am trying the sample for the GPS driver with a raspberry pi 3 and the Ultimate GPS V3 breakout board.

Here is the full source code: https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/gps

The GPS board is connected following this schematics:
[image]

When launching the sample app, I get the following error:

```
com.example.androidthings.driversamples E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.example.androidthings.driversamples, PID: 1299
   java.nio.BufferOverflowException
       at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:508)
       at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:142)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.processBuffer(NmeaGpsModule.java:178)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.readUartBuffer(NmeaGpsModule.java:160)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.access$000(NmeaGpsModule.java:35)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule$1.onUartDeviceDataAvailable(NmeaGpsModule.java:139)
       at com.google.android.things.pio.UartDevice$UartDeviceCallbackDispatch.dispatchInterruptEvent(UartDevice.java:507)
       at com.google.android.things.pio.CallbackDispatch.onFileDescriptorEvents(CallbackDispatch.java:127)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.dispatchEvents(MessageQueue.java:282)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

---

### Update 1

After enabling the debug in the contrib-driver project, I see a new error: `W/NmeaParser: Invalid checksum (62), expected 108`

```
12-28 17:53:28.638 1378-1378/com.example.androidthings.driversamples D/XXX: Debug version used
12-28 17:53:29.451 1378-1378/com.example.androidthings.driversamples I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-28 17:53:29.862 1378-1378/com.example.androidthings.driversamples W/NmeaParser: Invalid checksum (62), expected 108
12-28 17:53:29.862 1378-1378/com.example.androidthings.driversamples D/XXX: Buffer reset
12-28 17:53:30.427 1378-1378/com.example.androidthings.driversamples D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-28 17:53:30.428 1378-1378/com.example.androidthings.driversamples E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.androidthings.driversamples, PID: 1378
   java.nio.BufferOverflowException
       at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:508)
       at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:142)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.processBuffer(NmeaGpsModule.java:179)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.readUartBuffer(NmeaGpsModule.java:161)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.access$000(NmeaGpsModule.java:35)
       at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule$1.onUartDeviceDataAvailable(NmeaGpsModule.java:140)
       at com.google.android.things.pio.UartDevice$UartDeviceCallbackDispatch.dispatchInterruptEvent(UartDevice.java:507)
       at com.google.android.things.pio.CallbackDispatch.onFileDescriptorEvents(CallbackDispatch.java:127)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.dispatchEvents(MessageQueue.java:282)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
12-28 17:53:30.439 1378-1378/com.example.androidthings.driversamples I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1378 SIG: 9
```

---

### Update 2

After increasing the buffer size by 4, I was able to get few messages in. I see some messages have some junk that would explain the overflow:

```
12-28 23:38:17.393 2366-2366/? D/XXX: message: ��GPGGA,233817.000,3742.1931,N,12208.3976,W,1,04,1.96,164.3,M,-25.5,M,,*58
12-28 23:38:17.394 2366-2366/? D/XXX: Buffer reset
12-28 23:38:17.394 2366-2366/? D/XXX: message: GPGSA,A,3,23,03,26,22,,,,,,,,,2.20,1.96,1.00*0B
12-28 23:38:17.395 2366-2366/? D/XXX: Buffer reset
12-28 23:38:17.544 2366-2366/com.example.androidthings.driversamples D/XXX: message: GP��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������RMC,233817.000,A��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������,3742.1931,N,12208.3976,W,0.42,205.67,281216,,,A*71
12-28 23:38:17.545 2366-2366/com.example.androidthings.driversamples D/XXX: Buffer reset
12-28 23:38:17.545 2366-2366/com.example.androidthings.driversamples D/XXX: message: GPVTG,205.67,T,,M,0.42,N,0.78,K,A*32
12-28 23:38:17.546 2366-2366/com.example.androidthings.driversamples D/XXX: Buffer reset
```

I have no idea where that junk could come from...

Comment: looks like the message is too big for the buffer: https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaGpsModule.java#L178

Comment: I don't know much about UART.. Is there a setting for the message size?

Comment: the update shows its printing this: https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaParser.java#L124 sorry I can't help much but I found another checksum implementation you can check against: https://github.com/wdalmut/libgps/blob/master/src/nmea.c#L131 (granted in c)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases processBuffer() will process the whole buffer (512 bytes) regardless of how many bytes are read from the UART. If it happens to miss a start or end character you can end up with a lot of '0' in the message buffer. You can modify [this](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaGpsModule.java#L159) to be like this:

```
int count;
while ((count = uart.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
  processBuffer(buffer, count);
}
```

then modify [this](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaGpsModule.java#L170) to be more like this:

```
private void processBuffer(byte[] buffer, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (mParser.getFrameStart() == buffer[i]) {
            handleFrameStart();
        } else if (mParser.getFrameEnd() == buffer[i]) {
            handleFrameEnd();
        } else {
            //Insert all other characters into the buffer
            mMessageBuffer.put(buffer[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you won't be filling the message buffer with garbage if an end character gets dropped. I noticed this happening in a project I'm working on that uses this source code. The readUartBuffer() method can read split messages, i.e., the start or end of a message. If it does, bad things happen.

Comment: That works! I m still dropping a lot of packets but at least I can get some of the messages correctly. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DaveMcKelvie would you be willing to make a pull request with these improvements?

Comment: @Karakuri yep, sure I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the demo code https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/driversamples/GpsActivity.java#L35 the Baud rate is set correctly as per the data sheet: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-ultimate-gps.pdf

And looking at the contrib-driver for `NmeaGpsModule` the message buffer length is twice the size of the buffer read from the driver https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaGpsModule.java#L169 so it can't overflow with just one read.

**A theory for the issue could be that the message buffer is not being cleared after it receives data** - therefore you get a `BufferOverflowException` after a few packets.

The buffer is reset in 2 places:

When a new frame starts:

https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaGpsModule.java#L187

Or when a frame ends:

https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaGpsModule.java#L209

---

I don't have the hardware to debug your issue, however I can recommend how you could do it:

*This goes for anyone wanting to debug a **contrib-driver***

Fork / Make a copy of this android library: https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/gps

Edit the [build.gradle](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/build.gradle) to add this dependency: https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release (follow the README for instructions).

Once you add that dependency the `build.gradle` will look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release' // new code

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
   }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.4.0'  // new code
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.1-devpreview'
}

publish {  // new code
    userOrg = 'google'
    groupId = 'com.google.android.things.contrib'
    artifactId = 'driver-gps'
    publishVersion = '0.1-DEBUG'
}
```

Now you can release your own version of the GPS driver for debugging, but first:

Edit the java files, to add logging. In the `NmeaGpsModule.java` of your fork/copy, make two changes:

```
private void init(UartDevice device, int baudRate, Handler handler) throws IOException {
    Log.d("XXX", "MY VERSION BEING USED"); // new code
    mDevice = device;
    mDevice.setBaudrate(baudRate);
    mDevice.registerUartDeviceCallback(mCallback, handler);

    mParser = new NmeaParser();
}
```

and

```
private void resetBuffer() {
    Log.d("XXX", "BUFFER BEING RESET");  // new code
    mMessageBuffer.clear();
    mFrameFlag = false;
}
```

To release this version run this command in a terminal from the same folder as the `build.gradle`:

```
 ./gradlew clean build bintrayUpload -PdryRun=true
```

Now you have released a dependency!
Back in your application (in this case the `driver-samples`) https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/blob/master/gps/build.gradle#L39:

Change the `build.gradle` to have a different dependency:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-gps:0.1'
```

becomes

```
 compile 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-gps:0.1-DEBUG'
```

and tell it to look locally for this dependency:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
```

Now rerun the application and you should see your logs! First the sanity log to prove it worked `"MY VERSION BEING USED"` then the buffer being reset `"BUFFER BEING RESET"` if the buffer isn't being reset .. you need to check your hard wiring or add more logs to figure out why.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, going to check on that.

Comment: I added an update to my question with the result of the test you suggested.